# Conexión con hosting mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Buenas, estoy tratando de conectar con un hosting gratuito, pero me tira [error en la conexion](http://prntscr.com/dey8j0)(***Ocurrio un error: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.***), no se realmente porque será, estoy usando mysqlconnector. Y lo unico que agregue al siguiente codigo es un formulario con un boton que ejecuta el constructor.

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;

    public class Conexion
    {
        private static Connection conexion;
        private static final String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        private static final String usuario="eshos_19255445";
        private static final String password="miPass";
        private static final String url="jdbc:mysql://sql104.eshost.com.ar:3306/eshos_19255445_pruebaDB";

        public Conexion()
        {
            conexion=null;

            try 
            {
                Class.forName(driver);
                conexion=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, password);

                if(conexion != null)
                    System.out.println("Conexion establecida :=)");
            } 
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.err.println("Ocurrio un error: "+e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        public static Connection getConexion()
        {
            return conexion;
        }

        public void desconectar()
        {
            conexion=null;
        }

    }
```

Los datos los pueden ver en esta imagen [datos](http://prntscr.com/dey7kp)

Gracias saludos!

Comment: ¿Cual es el error?

Comment: Esta la imagen en el error, recien la puse

Comment: Gracias :) Pero toma en cuenta que se prefiere incluir texto en las preguntas mas bien que imágenes cuando es posible. Entre otras cosas, esto permite que esta página se pueda conseguir por Google por ejemplo si alguien hace una búsqueda por el mensaje del error. Esto le agrega valor a tu pregunta para la comunidad.

Comment: Tal vez no es un problema con el código sino con el servidor. ¿Has probado conectando a la base de datos usando MySQL Workbench por ejemplo?

Comment: No, nunca lo use, soy nuevo con el tema de las bd (todavia no curse la materia en la universidad) y queria ir viendo algo.

Comment: Creo que algo está mal con el servidor. Puedo establecer una conexión usando `telnet sql104.eshost.com.ar 3306`, pero al tratar `mysql --host sql104.eshost.com.ar`, recibo un error similar al tuyo: `ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0`

Comment: Y una sugerencia adicional aparte, para referencia futura, cuando compartes el error, siempre es bueno de incluir el stack trace completo del error.

Comment: Perdon mi ignorancia, que seria el stack trace completo? Y como lo obtengo?

Comment: Sería el resultado de `e.toString()` en vez de `e.getMessage()`.

Comment: Gracias, lo cambien y me tira lo mismo pero agregando esto: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El mensaje está explicando que hay un problema de comunicaciones que impide el establecimiento e intercambio de datos con el servidor.

Generalmente se produce una `conexión rechazada por el servidor` cuando el servidor MySQL está apagado, un mensaje `expiró el tiempo de conexión` si hay un problema de filtrado de tráfico (un cortafuegos que filtra el puerto de MySQL) o un mensaje `la conexión fue reiniciada por el servidor` si el servidor recibe la conexión pero la cierra tras aceptar la conexión (quizá tras comprobar la IP fuente u otra comprobación similar).

Tiene toda la pinta que el mensaje se debe a uno de esos problemas. ¿Qué configuración IP tiene el servidor MySQL? ¿Soporta conexiones externas?

Busca el parámetro [`bind-address`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address) en el archivo `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` o `my.ini` o el que use tu servidor. Si tienes configurado `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` cámbialo por (o agrégalo si no lo tenías) `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`.

Eso permitirá la recepción de conexiones desde cualquier equipo externo, no sólo desde el mismo equipo (`localhost` o `127.0.0.1`).

Comment: Va a ser complicado que encuentre eso, el server que uso se llama eshost, es gratuito y es mi primera experiencia con mysql

Comment: Entonces es muy probable que sólo soporte conexiones provenientes de sus propios servidores, y no desde máquinas externas a su red.

Comment: Conoces algun hosting gratuito como para hacer pruebas?

Comment: Tenias razon, era exactamente por eso, al parecer la mayoria de los servidores gratuitos no soportan conexiones externas

Comment: Siempre puedes hacer uso de servicios de VPS económicos o bien usar servicios REST para acceder a tu base de datos a través de HTTPS. MySQL tiene un módulo (en pruebas) llamado [MySQL HTTP plugin](http://labs.mysql.com/) que soporte consultas a la base de datos a través de una interfaz RESTful, con resultados en JSON ([ver este artículo](https://www.infoq.com/news/2014/09/MySQL-REST)). Puede servirte para acceder a tus datos incluso cuando el usuario está tras un firewall restrictivo que no permita tráfico hacia/desde el puerto 3306.

Comment: Ups, olvidé decir que este servicio tendrás que instalarlo en un servidor VPS, te recomiendo que hagas pruebas con [una instancia VPS gratuita de Cloud9](https://c9.io/).

Comment: Muchas gracias por la info! Empezaré a incursionar en cuanto termine con los finales!